# The base of an isosceles triangle lies in a plane

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, solid-geometry

The vertex $B$ of an isosceles $\triangle ABC$ $(AB=BC)$ does NOT lie on the plane $\alpha$, but the base $AC=18$ of the triangle lies in the plane. The angle between $CB$ and $\alpha$ is $60^\circ$. Find the angle $\measuredangle(BM,\alpha)$ where $BM$ is the median of the triangle and $AB=15$.

Is the given angle $\measuredangle ACB=60^\circ$? Because the orthogonal projection of $BC$ is the line $MC$ or not? Is the orthogonal projection of the point $B$ the point $M$ in $\alpha$ and why? I am not sure I understand which angle I am supposed to find. We can use the fact that $BM\perp AC$ because the triangle is isosceles, but what else? Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: By definition of median, M is the midpoint of AC. There is no reason to believe that is the orthogonal projection of B onto alpha, cause that would only be the case if the triangle was vertical, i.e. if the angle we are asked to find were 90 degrees.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, so what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Draw a picture first to get a feel of the problem. If you are having trouble visualising it, cut out a triangular piece of cardboard or paper, mark the corners A,B,C, think of the table as the plane alpha, and play around with it so that you can see what is going on.

Comment: If $H$ is the projection of $B$ on $\alpha$, then $BH=BC\cdot\sin60°={15\over2}\sqrt3$. Hence: $\sin\angle BMH=BH/BM={5\over8}\sqrt3>1$, impossible.

Comment: There is a point on the plane $\alpha$ where the normal goes through $B$; call this point $N$. Then you can take the angle given as $60^\circ$ as referring to $\angle BCN$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine isosceles $\triangle ABC$ as being vertical on the plane $\alpha$, $AC$ contained in $\alpha$. $\triangle BMC$ is a $3-4-5$ triangle right-angled at $M$.

Now tilt the triangle, keeping $AC$ fixed, so $B$ moves closer to the plane. Call the projection of $B$, $P$. As $ABC$ is isosceles, $P$ will move on the perpendicular bisector of $AC$, away from $M$. Clearly in triangle $BPC$, right-angled at $P$, $\angle BCP$ is the angle between $BC$ and $\alpha$.

Initially in the vertical position, $P$ was at $M$ and $\angle BCP \approx 53.1^{\circ}$. As $B$ moves closer to the plane, this angle will reduce and go to zero when $B$ finally lies in the plane.

Thus the data $\angle BCP= 60^{\circ}$ is false; it is not compatible with $BC=15, AC=18$. $\angle BCP\le \arcsin (4/5)\approx 53.1^{\circ}$ always.

Comment: May I ask you what do you mean by "as being vertical on the plane $\alpha$"? Why is $\triangle BMC$ a 3-4-5 triangle right-angled at $M$?

Comment: @Medi Being vertical means, $B$ is directly above base $AC$. Its projection $P$ coincides with $M$. For second question, you already found sides of $BC$ - $9:12:15=3:4:5$. By calling it a $3-4-5$, I meant to say, its acute angles are known $\approx 37.9^{\circ}, 53.1^{\circ}$.

Comment: Think of plane $\alpha$ as the ground, and the triangle as a building, with base $AC$ on the ground. Being vertical means, it is not tilted at all.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! But why the projection of $B$ coincides with $M$? If $B$ is directly above base $AC$ can't $P\in AC, P\ne M$?

Comment: Because $ABC$ is isosceles and $B$ is directly over $M$ (median and altitude of isosceles triangle coincide).

Comment: Thank you, I got that. But I don't think $P$ will move on the perpendicular bisector of $AC$, because the projection of $B$ lies on $AC$ only when $\triangle ABC$ is vertical on the plane $\alpha$. I added a diagram in the post.

Comment: May I ask why $\measuredangle AMD=90^\circ$?

Comment: By pythagoras $AD^2=AB^2-BD^2=BC^2-BD^2=CD^2$ and $AMD \cong CMD$ by SSS.

Comment: Thank you again!